# unable to set transform origin in firefox

Tags: css, svg, css-animations, svg-animate

I am trying to Create an animation with SVG and CSS3 And it works fine on Chrome but doesn't work on Firefox 
I have tried adding `-moz-` prefix to `transform-origin:` but yet it's not working

[here](https://261b467e516e9d54f239ca12dc033983fa62cc44.googledrive.com/host/0B0vEuOxa0lxITXdneUd6c1p3aVE/ani.html) is the live sample I have created

Css Rules I have added is:

```
#aniBin {
  overflow: visible;
}
#Bin:hover #cap {
  transition-duration: 400ms;
  transform: rotate(-150deg);
  transform-origin:0% 90%;
  -moz-transform-origin:0% 90%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transform-origin` is not currently supported with SVG in Firefox if percentages are used as units.
Try using pixels:

```
transform-origin:0 10px;
```